Token Generating but not authorizing apis to access data
Token is generating successfully, after generating token i am authorizing it. Here is all ok,
But the problem is when I am using the apis which I have given authorized swagger giving 401 (unauthorised error) or bearer "token invalid" error.
Code For Generating Token
public class TokenRepository(IConfiguration configuration): ITokenRepository {
  public string CreateJwtToken(IdentityUser user, List < string > roles) {
    var claims = new List < Claim > {
      new(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UserName)
    };

    foreach(var role in roles) {
      claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }
    var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]);
    var credentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
      configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
      claims,
      expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(15),
      signingCredentials: credentials);

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
  }
}

Login Code
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login")]
public async Task < IActionResult > Login([FromBody] AuthLoginRequest authLoginRequest) //LoginRequest have two property - username, password
{
  var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(authLoginRequest.Username);
  if (user != null) {
    var isValid = await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, authLoginRequest.Password);
    if (isValid) {
      var roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
      if (roles != null) {
        string jwtToken = tokenRepository.CreateJwtToken(user, roles.ToList());
        return Ok(new JwtTokenDto {
          JwtToken = jwtToken
        });
      }
    }
  }

  return BadRequest("Username or Password is Incorrect");
}

I want to authorize my apis

How you configure your web api for jtw authentication in web api program.cs?
